# Why is inbuf = xmalloc (insize + page_size - 1)?

Tags: c, linux, cat

I'm reading cat source code, but I dont understand the following piece of code

```
insize = MAX (insize, outsize);
inbuf = xmalloc (insize + page_size - 1);
```

Why is the buffer created with a size of `insize + page_size -1`?

Comment: If you want to ask such a tool-specific question, please at least give information on file, line number and version of the source code.

Comment: Add context to the question, and add a link to the full source file.

Comment: Obviously whoever wrote that wants to allocate some more space than given by `insize`/`outsize`. To find out why, you have to look at how the allocated space is used in that program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common idiom used when you need to allocate a buffer that will be aligned on a page boundary (page-aligned buffers are required by various APIs and can also improve memory throughput). There is no portable way to ask `malloc` for a page-aligned buffer, so asking for  `x + PAGE_SIZE-1` bytes guarantees that you will be able to round the resulting pointer up to the next page boundary and still have it point to a block of at least `x` bytes.